# How to get git log with color and paging on cygwin?

Tags: git, logging, cygwin

I'd like to have colored git logs with paging on cygwin.

I managed to get colored logs with

```
git log --color=always
```

If I do

```
git log --color=always | less
```

I get paging, but the color commands are printed instead of interpreded

```
ESC[33mcommit b4dbe28f459adf0df1784d3a597628cc27abf836ESC[m
Author: Ernst Pluess <mail@address.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 18 13:23:07 2013 +0200

    Changed to UTF-8
```

On my OSX box colors and paging is the default behaviour for git log on the shell. How can I get the same for cygwin on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to configure git globally (on cygwin at least) by running

`git config --global core.pager 'C:/cygwin64/bin/less.exe'`

This way running `git log` shows a paged and colorized output.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
less -R
```

instead of just less to pass color ANSI control characters through to the terminal.

You can also set the LESS environment variable to

```
LESS=-R
```

to make this default behaviour.